# Exception shoutcast and java

Tags: java, shoutcast

I trying to write a code to stream from shoutcast server
and I use the below code and give me `javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException` 
how I can solve the exception

```
  public static void streamSampledAudio(URL url)
        throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException,
               LineUnavailableException
    {
        AudioInputStream ain = null;  // We read audio data from here
        SourceDataLine line = null;   // And write it here.

        try {
             InputStream is = url.openStream();
             BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream( is );
            ain=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bis);

            AudioFormat format = ain.getFormat( );
            DataLine.Info info=new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class,format);

            if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
                AudioFormat pcm =
                    new AudioFormat(format.getSampleRate( ), 16,
                                    format.getChannels( ), true, false);

                ain = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(pcm, ain);

                format = ain.getFormat( ); 
                info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
            }

            line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open(format);  

            int framesize = format.getFrameSize( );
            byte[  ] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024 * framesize]; // the buffer
            int numbytes = 0;                               // how many bytes

            boolean started = false;

            for(;;) {  // We'll exit the loop when we reach the end of stream
                int bytesread=ain.read(buffer,numbytes,buffer.length-numbytes);
                if (bytesread == -1) break;
                numbytes += bytesread;

                if (!started) {
                    line.start( );
                    started = true;
                }

                int bytestowrite = (numbytes/framesize)*framesize;

                line.write(buffer, 0, bytestowrite);
                int remaining = numbytes - bytestowrite;
                if (remaining > 0)
                    System.arraycopy(buffer,bytestowrite,buffer,0,remaining);
                numbytes = remaining;
            }

            line.drain( );
        }
        finally { // Always relinquish the resources we use
            if (line != null) line.close( );
            if (ain != null) ain.close( );
        }
    }
```

and give me an exception

```
  Exception in thread "main" javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio
 input stream from input stream
        at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at test.PlaySoundStream.streamSampledAudio(PlaySoundStream.java:40)
        at test.PlaySoundStream.main(PlaySoundStream.java:21)
```

can help me to solve the exception 
or **tell me about away can stream by it from shoutcast**

Answer (score 0):

I try this code to download MP3 from shoutcast and then you can play sound

```
  public class DownloadMP3 {

             private boolean halt = false;
      public static final String DEFAULT_HOST = "127.0.0.1";
      protected String host = "url";
      public static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 80;
      protected int port = 8568;
      public static final int DEFAULT_TOTAL_SIZE = 0;
      protected long totalSize = 0L;
      public static final int DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE = 0;
      long chunkSize = 0L;
      public static final String DEFAULT_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = ".";
      File outputDirectory = new File("D:\\");

      public static void main(String[  ] args) throws Exception {
         DownloadMP3 d = new DownloadMP3();

         d.run();
      }

      public void run()
      {
        Socket localSocket = null;
        PrintWriter localPrintWriter = null;
        BufferedInputStream localBufferedInputStream = null;
        FileOutputStream localFileOutputStream = null;
        try
        {
          writeMessage("Opening connection to " + this.host + ":" + this.port);

          localSocket = new Socket(this.host, this.port);
          localPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(localSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
          localBufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(localSocket.getInputStream());

          localPrintWriter.print("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
          localPrintWriter.flush();

          byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[1024];
          long l1 = 0L;
          long l2 = 0L;
          int i = 1;
          File localFile = null;

          writeMessage("Host contacted, waiting for response...");
          try
          {
            int k = 0;
            int m;

            writeMessage("Recieving Data....");
            int j;
            while ((j = localBufferedInputStream.read(arrayOfByte)) != -1) {
              if ((localFileOutputStream == null) || ((this.chunkSize > 0L) && (l2 + j >= this.chunkSize))) {
                m = findSync(arrayOfByte, 0, j);
                if (m == -1) {
                  m = j;
                }
                if (localFileOutputStream != null)
                {
                  localFileOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte, 0, m);
                }

                if (localFileOutputStream != null) {
                  localFileOutputStream.close();
                }

                while ((localFile = new File(this.outputDirectory, this.host + '-' + this.port + '-' + formatFileNum(i++) + ".mp3")).exists());
                writeMessage("Saving to file: " + localFile);

                localFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(localFile);
                l2 = 0L;

                localFileOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte, m, j - m);
                l2 += j - m;
              } else {
                localFileOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte, 0, j);
                l2 += j;
              }

              if ((this.totalSize > 0L) && (l1 >= this.totalSize)) {
                writeMessage("Capture completed successfully.");

              if (this.halt) {
                writeMessage("Capture interruted.");

              }
            }
            writeErrorMessage("Connection closed by host.");
            return;
          } catch (IOException localIOException2) {
            if (this.halt)
              writeMessage("Capture interruted.");
            else {
              writeErrorMessage(localIOException2.getMessage());
            }

          } finally {
            if (localFileOutputStream != null)
              localFileOutputStream.close();
          }
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException localUnknownHostException) {
          writeErrorMessage("Unknown host: " + this.host);

          return;
        } catch (IOException localIOException1) {
          writeErrorMessage("Could not connect to " + this.host + " on port " + this.port);

        }
        finally {
          if (localPrintWriter != null) {
            localPrintWriter.close();
          }
          if (localBufferedInputStream != null)
            try {
              localBufferedInputStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException localIOException3) {
            }
          if (localSocket != null)
            try {
              localSocket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException localIOException4)
            {
            }
        }
      }

      private static int findSync(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
      {
        for (int i = paramInt1; i < paramInt2 - 1; i++) {
          if (((paramArrayOfByte[i] & 0xFF) == 255) && ((paramArrayOfByte[(i + 1)] & 0xE0) == 224)) {
            return i;
          }
        }
        return -1;
      }

      private static String formatFileNum(int paramInt)
      {
        if (paramInt < 10)
          return "00" + paramInt;
        if (paramInt < 100) {
          return "0" + paramInt;
        }
        return "" + paramInt;
      }

      protected void writeMessage(String paramString)
      {

          System.out.println(paramString);
      }

      protected void writeErrorMessage(String paramString)
      {

          System.err.println(paramString);
      }
}
```